# Pessoa acessar duas páginas diferentes, referenciando o mesmo nome no localstorage

Tags: javascript

Fiz um script onde, a página principal que a pessoa acessa, salva a url da página no localstorage, e após clicar no botão, ele é redirecionado pra uma nova página onde o script identifica qual página ele estava e toma uma decisão no condicional.

```
var meu_storage = localStorage
    var paginaAnterior = meu_storage['pagina']
```

Minha dúvida é: Caso a pessoa acesse uma página (e não clica no botão), mas depois, acessa outra página que também vai ter o mesmo código salvando o window.location.href no localstorage (com o mesmo nome). Será sobrescrito a ultima página que ele acessou ou dará problema no script?

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Já fez os testes e verificou os resultados?

Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Comment: *"ele é redirecionado pra uma nova página onde o script identifica qual página ele estava"* olá, uma dúvida: pq não faz isso passando o parâmetro na url por exemplo como querystring? acho que era mais fácil

Comment: Pois se trata de um site wordpress, seria possível fazer isso apenas usando código javascript? Se sim, tem algum artigo sobre?